Run Android tests in Azure: Type mismatch: inferred type is () -> String? but String? was expected
When I run the Azure pipeline of my Android project to run the tests, during the test step two gradle tasks fail, compileDebugKotlin and compileReleaseKotlin, with the error in the title, pointing exactly to this HttpLoggingInterceptor():
private fun getHttpClient(
    ): OkHttpClient {

        val logger = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        logger.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY

        val customLoggingInterceptor = CustomLoggingInterceptor(logger)

        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(
                BearerInterceptor { token }
            )
            .addInterceptor(
                customLoggingInterceptor
            )
            .addInterceptor(
                logger
            )
            .connectTimeout(
                CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS
            )
            .readTimeout(
                CONNECTION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS
            )
            .build()
    }

When I run both tasks locally, no error. Interceptor dependency is updated, and both local and azure use gradle wrapper 8.0.
Per comments, here is the yaml pipeline:
# Android
# Build your Android project with Gradle.
# Add steps that test, sign, and distribute the APK, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/android

# Pipeline to run the tests as a precondition to every direct commit / Pull Request to develop/main branches
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - main

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - develop
      - main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: my_subrepository
      type: git
      name: TheAzureProject/TheMainRepository

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: my_subrepository
  path: s/TheMainRepository/my_subrepository

- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
  displayName: Setup Java 17
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'

- task: Gradle@3
  displayName: Run Tests
  inputs:
    workingDirectory: 'TheMainRepository'
    gradleWrapperFile: 'TheMainRepository/gradlew'
    gradleOptions: '-Xmx3072m'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-*.xml'
    tasks: 'test'


Since the issue doesn’t occur locally, there might be differences in the environment or configurations between your local and the Azure pipeline.  You can list all environment variables using a terminal command in your local and in your pipeline to compare environment variables difference. You can check if the versions of Gradle and Java are the same in both environments. Please make sure that you are run a clean build in both environments to avoid issues related to cached files.

To get more detailed logs, you can set the variable system.debug to true in the pipeline or set -d or --debug option in Gradle task to get debug messages. By the way, can you please share the YAML of the pipeline to better troubleshoot it?

Found the cause, it turns out the pipeline uses the current branch only for the main project, it was using the default branch (main) for the git submodules, hence the error log pointing to a place that made no sense.
Lesson: If the project has Git submodules, make sure to force the pipeline to use the appropriate branch in those too. (I found out triggering a manual run, still working on adding that to the yaml file)

Hi Pedro, thanks for sharing the answer and share the yaml of the pipeline. You are using multiple repositories in your pipeline. The default branch is checked out unless you designate a specific ref.  Document reference.

exactly, in the resources->repositories-repository, a new 'ref: develop' line needs to be added, to make the git submodule pick that branch instead of the default 'main'

Thanks for your update and share the example. You can edit the answer to add the example to make it clearer. This may help others who have the same issue in the future. :)
